# Implementing a Treeview component using React

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx

Today after watching a getting started course about React, I tried to code my very first React component, a "treeview" as the title says. It does work, but as a newbie I know there are many improvement that can be done.

It receives a data array like the one below:

```
[{
    descp: 'UNE',
    url: '/tree/une',
    icon: 'icon-list',
    children: [
        {
            descp: 'ATI',
            url: '/tree/une/ati',
            icon: 'icon-layers',
            children: [{
                    descp: 'ATI-VC',
                    url: '/tree/une/ati/ativc',
                    icon: 'icon-pin',
                    children: []
                },
                {
                    descp: 'ATI-CMG',
                    url: '/tree/une/ati/aticmg',
                    icon: 'icon-pin',
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            descp: 'EMGEF',
            url: '/tree/une/emgef',
            icon: 'icon-layers',
            children: []
        },
        {
            descp: 'ECIE',
            url: '/tree/une/ecie',
            icon: 'icon-layers',
            children: []
        },
        {
            descp: 'GEYSEL',
            url: '/tree/une/geysel',
            icon: 'icon-layers',
            children: []
        }
    ]
}]
```

Maybe the data format can be improve as well but the real deal is the component:

```
const MyTree = (props) => {
    const { list } = props;
    return (
        list.map((child,i)=>
            <MyTreeNestedItems key={i} data={child} />
        )
    );
};


const MyTreeNestedItems = (props) => {
    const { data } = props;

    const createChildren = (list) => {
        return (
            list.map((child,i)=>
                <MyTreeNestedItems key={i} data={child} />
            )
        )
    }

    let children = null;
    if (data.children.length) {
        children = createChildren(data.children);
    }

    return (
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                <span className={data.icon}></span> {" "}
                { data.descp }
            </a>
            <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>{children}</ul>
        </li>
    );
};

render(<MyTree list={tree} />,document.querySelector('.js-mytree'));
```

Any tips would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might notice that `createChildren` is almost the same as `MyTree` -- the only difference is that `createChildren` takes its argument directly instead of as a props object. So with a small change we can remove `createChildren` entirely:

```
const MyTreeNestedItems = (props) => {
    const { data } = props;

    let children = null;
    if (data.children.length) {
      children = <MyTree list={data.children} />;
    }

    return (
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                <span className={data.icon}></span> {" "}
                { data.descp }
            </a>
            <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>{children}</ul>
        </li>
    );
}
```

This can be a bit more compact as so:

```
const MyTreeNestedItems = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                <span className={data.icon}></span> {" "}
                { data.descp }
            </a>
            <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
                {data.children.length ? <MyTree list={data.children} /> : null}
            </ul>
        </li>
    );
};
```

---

Currently this code renders invalid HTML -- it renders with a `<li>` as the top level element but `<li>` should only be contained in a `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>`.

Looking at the code so far, `<MyTree>` is rendered in two places -- it may be tempting to just add another `<ul>` around `<MyTree list={tree} />` in the `render()` call. But then we would have two occurrences of a structure like this: `<ul><MyTree/></ul>`. It'd be easier to just move the `<ul>` into the `<MyTree/>`.

With that, the code now looks like this:

```
const MyTree = ({ list }) => {
    return (
        <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
            {list.map((child,i)=> <MyTreeNestedItems key={i} data={child} />)}
        </ul>
    );
};

const MyTreeNestedItems = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                <span className={data.icon}></span> {" "}
                { data.descp }
            </a>
            {data.children.length ? <MyTree list={data.children} /> : null}
        </li>
    );
};

render(<MyTree list={tree} />, document.querySelector('.js-mytree'));
```

---

From here it's a matter of taste. Both of the components are just directly returning a value, so we can use short arrow function syntax now: `(...) => (value)` instead of `(...) => { return (value); }`

Also, the components are now simple enough that I would just combine the two.

All in, that leaves us with this final version of the code:

```
const MyTree = ({ list }) => (
    <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
        {list.map(({icon, descp, children}, i) => (
            <li className="nav-item" key={i}>
                <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                    <span className={icon} /> {descp}
                </a>
                {children.length ? <MyTree list={children} /> : null}
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
);

render(<MyTree list={tree} />, document.querySelector('.js-mytree'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot George, that's a great improvement of my code and explanation. Now in a few days I will be focusing on implementing collapse/expand functionality to the component.